# Is there an academic word that means "to split hairs over"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a higher register word that means to criticize something highly specific and inconsequential? Any synonym I can think of seems a little too vernacular, e.g. "to split hairs", "to nitpick". What's a more professional/academic way of saying this? I'd prefer a single word if one exists.

Comment: Try looking up: angels on the head of a pin.

Comment: The Talmudic term is [_pilpul_](https://www.google.com/search?q=pilpul), but that's a noun and not a verb.

Comment: BTW Nitpick and Split hairs are not exactly the same. To split hairs is about definitions and wording, while nit picking is about facts and content.  "London has over 10 million inhabitants" Split hairs = Actually the City of London is very small. Nitpicking = It's actually over 11 million now. Two different approaches to derail a main point!

Comment: @EnglishAdam My colleague was told he was being pedantic, and he replied: "Pedantry tends to involve a gratuitous display of knowledge. This is *nitpicking*." :-)

Comment: @EnglishAdam Currently the estimated population of Greater London is below 9 million </nitpicking>

Comment: For single-word requests, it's best to include an example sentence with a blank where the word would go.

Comment: @SusanW - "Pedant" is merely the name given by the ignorant to the accurate. That usually shuts people up for a second :-)

Comment: This is far from a professional/academic phrase but this is exactly what bikeshedding is. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bikeshedding

Comment: @EnglishAdam You're being overly pendantic. Oh, the irony.

Comment: An over-zealous attention to detail.

Comment: @EnglishAdam now you’re just being pedantic :-P

Comment: Define "academic word". The question is unclear.

Comment: "to commit pilotomy" at least sounds very academic

Comment: @Spratty yes.... nice, very nice... :-)

Comment: @MikeTheLiar bikeshedding: almost ... but isn't there the requirement that bikeshedding is specifically about debating an easy-to-grasp but marginal problem _whilst neglecting a more important but harder one_? (Though following your wiktionary link, I see that that nuance has disappeared into "Etymology")

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think 
**pedantry**
 would fit,
adjective: to be [pedantic](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pedantic)

> overly concerned with minute details or formalisms, especially in
>   teaching.

Comment: This is the best suggestion for formal academic use.

Comment: OP appears to be asking for a verb...

Comment: I was, however as @Strawberry pointed out on my answer "cavil" is just too pretentious/archaic. This one works well enough for me

Answer (score 26):

I found a possible answer:

### [Cavil](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cavil)

> to raise trivial and frivolous objection
>
> *The author **caviled** about the design of the book's cover*.

Comment: This may be too high a register.

Comment: @Strawberry Ooh, I must remember that one. What a nice way of saying one has never heard of the word.

Comment: @MrLister ;-) indeed

Comment: I have heard of it (she said in a pedantic voice) and I don't think it fits the use-case. It can be quite legit to cavil about something, nor does it have to be about small details.

Comment: well now you're just splitting hairs

Answer (score 22):

I would probably go with **quibble**.  You could equally use **fault-finding**.

**Carping** is another option, but that's nearly as informal as 'nit-picking', so I doubt you'll like it.

Comment: I found quibble earlier, but I wasn't sure if this was the correct usage. MW defines it as "to evade the point of an argument by caviling about words" which seems rather specific

Comment: @Zaya - That definition in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quibble) is just one of two meanings given, the second being *cavil* or *carp*. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quibble) doesn't say anything about *quibble* being specific to words. My life experience (30yrs U.S. 20 UK) is that *quibble* is what you'd use for this meaning and that *cavil*, though correct, is much less common and many of a typical audience won't know it.

Comment: @Zaya Originally, 'quibble' specifically meant complaining about tiny errors in latin grammar -- the word comes from 'quibus', which is a particularly tricky word in latin for reasons I won't go into here.  But over time the meaning has broadened to mean just in general "complaining about small things that don't actually matter".  The OED agrees with that usage, and doesn't draw any specific relation to being about word choice.

Answer (score 14):

As an adjective or noun, you can use

[**Picayune**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/picayune)

> An argument, fact, corner case, or other issue raised (often intentionally) that distracts from a larger issue at hand or fails to make any difference.
>
> *I don't like my debating class, the judges are too **picayune** and Dr. Moss always finds a way to disqualify people based on technicalities.*

Comment: Very good ... that'll have them running for their dictionaries!

Comment: Indeed.  How to derail a derailer, unless he is also a walking dictionary.

Comment: This is an amazing word. I love it to death. The etymology says its from the French word for penny, the most useless coin of all. Literally "arguing about pennies"

Comment: @SusanW - that'll have them _reaching_ for their dictionaries. (Most everyone has a dictionary in their pocket nowadays.)

Answer (score 11):

### [Pettifogging](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pettifogging)

can mean to place undue attention on small details. It's a bit more formal than some of the other suggestions, but is also somewhat archaic.

> The committee spent half the day pettifogging over some arcane rule and never got around to my proposal.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of engineering, programming, or other technical disciplines, there is also

[**Bikeshedding**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bikeshedding)

> Parkinson observed that a committee whose job is to approve plans for a nuclear power plant may spend the majority of its time on relatively unimportant but easy-to-grasp issues, such as what materials to use for the staff bikeshed, while neglecting the design of the power plant itself, which is far more important but also far more difficult to criticize constructively.
>
> *We were supposed to give our proposal to the client today but Jamie insisted on **bikeshedding** over the exact color of the cover page so we had to deliver the report later.*

This term is more informal, and it's jargon specific to a particular field so it might not be what you are looking for, but others who come across this question may find it useful.

Edit: I just realized @MikeTheLiar already proposed this word in [a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/498304/is-there-an-academic-word-that-means-to-split-hairs-over/498508#comment1202286_498304), but the comment was hidden as it had a low score.

Answer (score 2):

In a more pedantic way : tetrapiloctomie

Created by Umberto Eco from the Latin & Greek words Tetra (~4), Pilus (~hair) and ectomie (~cutting)

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C3%A9trapilectomie

Better tasted in French so it's quintessential pedantic ;)

Answer (score 0):

> **Nitpicking**
>   - Looking for small or unimportant errors or faults, especially in order to criticize unnecessarily. ([Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nitpicking))
>
> *‘It may therefore seem like philosophical nit-picking if I criticise some of his arguments for getting to those conclusions.’*
>
> *‘A first-year student at Williams may well become frustrated with such fastidious nit-picking.’* ([Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nitpicking))

Comment: Nitpick was actually discarded by the OP but I think it's formal enough.

Comment: Is Urban Dictionary a legit source on this SE?

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser - It depends on the question. If someone is looking for newfangled slang, it can be an excellent resource; however, when the OP is looking for something in a "professional/academic" register, it's probably a poor choice, especially with so many other dictionaries available.